# Why does this regular expression suppress more than I was expecting?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to suppress strings that begin with `[T` *without doing a positive match and negating the results*.

```
my @tests = ("OT", "[T","NOT EXCLUDED");
foreach my $test (@tests)
{
 #match from start of string, 
 #include 'Not left sq bracket' then include 'Not capital T'
 if ($test =~ /^[^\[][^T]/)  #equivalent to /^[^\x5B][^T]/
 {
  print $test,"\n";
 }
}
```

Outputs

```
NOT EXCLUDED
```

My question is, can somebody tell me why `OT` is being excluded in the above example?

**EDIT**
Thanks for your replies so far everybody, I can see I was being a bit stoopid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex `^[^\[][^T]` matches string that begin with a character other than `[` followed by a character other than `T`.

Since `OT` has `T` as 2nd character, it is not matched.

If you want to match any string other than those that begin with `[T`, you can do:

```
if ($test =~ /^(?!\[T)/) {
   print $test,"\n";
}
```

Comment: am back from perldoc. thanks for the info about the negative look-ahead assertion. I chose this answer because you provided a way of suppressing strings without having to do a positive match and negating the results.

Answer (score 1):

[YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAPE%3a%3aRegex%3a%3aExplain) can be helpful:

```
$ perl -MYAPE::Regex::Explain -E 'say YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr/^[^\[][^T]/)->explain'
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^[^\[][^T])

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\[]                    any character except: '\['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^T]                     any character except: 'T'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Regex::Explain.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex translates to:

> From start of the input, match anything but an open square bracket (**[**) followed by anything but a capital T

- OT fails to match
- [T as well

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is equivalent to "begins with NOT [ and second one is NOT T", so the only one that passes is NOT EXCLUDED, because in OT, the second letter is T